# C Rounding up float

Tags: c, rounding

I have some float, like: 7.66, 4.26,897.18...

I want to round them up to the higher integer:

```
* 6.87 -> 7

* 5.312 -> 6

* 67.055 -> 68

* 9965.49 -> 9966

* etc.
```

How should I do that?

Thank You!

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to use `ceil`, you could try adding 1 and then truncating to `int`, but you'd have to have a special case to detect the case where your original number had no fractional part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
   double num = 6.87;
   int result;
   result = ceil(num);
   printf("Ceiling integer of %.2f = %d", num, result);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with that conversion to `int` as that's vulnerable to overflow.

Comment: @Bathsheba You are completely right, this snippet is only to show him the method; *guards and check are essential always*

Comment: @SteveSummit indeed its also valid option, wasn't my go to answer but it will work; I think that your type of answer might confuse programmer new to C

Comment: @DavidS Sorry, meant to comment on the original question, not your answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I need the float be rounded allways up. Even 2.00007 to became 3.

Comment: @utor this is exactly what *ceil()* does, it rounds to the closest from the top

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`ceil`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/) function from `math.h`

Comment: Thanks. But I need the float be rounded allways up. Even 2.00007 to became 3.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ceil` or `ceilf` in `math.h`. The signatures are

```
double ceil(double arg);
```

and

```
float ceilf(float arg);
```

Cast the result to an integral type if necessary, taking steps to ensure you don't overflow that type (which is one reason why the return types of `ceil` and `ceilf` are the same as the input type).

Comment: Thanks. But I need the float be rounded allways up. Even 2.00007 to became 3.

Comment: @utor: Well that's what happens. Did you not try it?